# Spring (Boot) application and csrf

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I use this statements in the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure` method to secure my application. 
If csrf is disabled (`http.csrf().disable();`) than everything works fine, if I remove this line than I get an exception (Forbidden 403).
It is not clear for me why - I want to be safe against csrf- attack. 
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    final List<String> activeProfiles = Arrays.asList(environment.getActiveProfiles());

    final CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter csrfFilter = csrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter();
    http.addFilterAfter(csrfFilter, CsrfFilter.class).headers().cacheControl().xssProtection();

    http.csrf().disable();
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    final String[] restEndpointsToSecure = WebSecurityConfig.restEndpointsToSecure;
    for (final String endpoint : restEndpointsToSecure) {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/" + endpoint + "/**").hasRole(UserRoleEnum.USER.toString());
    }
    xAuthTokenConfigurer.setDetailsService(userDetailsServiceBean());
    final SecurityConfigurer<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> securityConfigurerAdapter = xAuthTokenConfigurer;
    http.apply(securityConfigurerAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **[Spring Security CSRF Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf)**

You need to include the token in your requests.  If you use Thymeleaf as your templating engine, this is handled automatically.  The documentation also describes how to handle Ajax as well.

Comment: I do include a token into the requests of my application, but the problem is the first request (before login) - at this time no token exists and there - it seems to me, csrf is blocking my first request. How can I handle this? Thanks a lot.